# Unexplained crashes iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, crash, cocos2d-iphone

I'm currently working on a game for iPhone/iPad using Cocos2D.
On the simulator it works fine and can run for hours, without any problems.
But on a device, it runs for some time and then just crashes out of nowhere. The debug console gives no error message, typing in "bt" just returns "No stack." and it doesn't generate a crash report.
It mostly crashes when loading the main menu or a new level but it can happen while playing a level as well.

Any ideas on how to debug this?

Comment: It sounds like it could be a memory leak. Have you checked the app with the 'leaks' tool?

Comment: Not really a solution, but you should check the application behavior with Instruments while it runs (by doing Project -> Analyze) on your device, to see if there is any suspicious memory usage patterns or other hints for bogus behiors.

Comment: It is 99% that it is a memory leak.

Comment: Memory leak, i have the same problem whit my app, just run a initial analysis, to get an idea about the leak  clean the project then analysis, on the Simulator it can run for hours without problem because it basically has you computers runnable memory available .

Comment: I have analyzed it with instruments on the simulator (it leaks about 50kb each time the menu/level is loaded). The random crash only happens on older devices. Running on a device through instruments now.

Comment: It refuses to launch through instruments. Loads for a few seconds and then crashes.

Comment: What is the game loading the time it crashes? which device are you testing it on? How big are the game assestes (dimension vise)?

Comment: I have no idea what the game is loading at the time since it can happen at any time after a few minutes of gameplay. I'm testing it on a first generation iPad (since it has the least memory available of the devices we are going to support). The assets can range from really small (32x32) to large spritesheets (animations) and background items (mountains, trees, etc).

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the instruments sorted in live bytes on device.

Comment: http://img849.imageshack.us/img849/8034/screenshot20111118at204.png   The graph above is really inaccurate on a device. I played until it crashed.

Comment: Did you tried Analyze code? It is a bit under launch with instrument in the build menu. The problem is with a high probability a memory allocation problem. For example, you dealloc something twice, or forget to alloc something, or forget to retain an object.

Comment: Yeah, I have analyzed it many times. Anyways, after messing around with instruments (I'm new to objective-C and iOS) I found out that it is a memory leak. A rather large one in fact but it doesn't happen every time. This will probably take some time since I'm pretty sure I clean up after each scene transition and whenever an object dies. Going to mess around some more and try to find out what's wrong...

Comment: I have decided to migrate the project to ARC but am having some trouble. Whenever I try to refactor the project, XCode crashes. When it does not crash, all I get is an empty "select targets to convert" popup. What could be the problem?

Comment: I managed to convert the project to ARC over the holidays and that solved most of the problems (still some leaks here and there). Still have some cleaning up to do and stability issues.

Answer (score 0):

You should really read about memory management in objective-c

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html

When I first switched to programming in objective-c (from C#/Java background), I had a lot of problems too. Once I understood memory management in objective-c, I rarely have those kind of problems. I don't use arc.

Whenever you alloc & init an object, the retain count is 1. You should remember to release these objects at some point. If you use other methods, then you get an autorelease object. That is the convention.

The time you will save is really worth it.